# CakePHP 'autoRender = false' does not working. Still gives missing view error

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.0.4 (Doing Changes in existing project)

My controller function is..

```
class PagesController extends AppController {
    public function getlocations($string = ''){
        $this->autoRender = false;             
        $aResult = array(0=>'Florida', 1=>'London');
        echo json_encode($aResult);
    }
}
```

And also I have try $this->autoLayout = $this->autoRender = false;

When I am calling this action directly in browser mysite/app/pages/getlocations it will give following error

```
View file "/home/mysite/public_html/testing/app/View/Pages/g.ctp" is missing.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Create a `/View/Ajax/json.ctp` view:**

```
<?php
if(!empty($data)) echo json_encode($data);
```

**Then in the action:**

```
$this->set('data', array(0=>'Florida', 1=>'London'));
$this->layout = false;
$this->render('/Ajax/json');
```

Comment: This is a good answer as this uses the View to output content rather than the Controller. This is how Cake should be being used.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make it work following the Cake way.

First you have to add the following code to your routes file:

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Next, in the controller add the 'RequestHandler' to your components array and serialize your result in your getlocations function:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function getlocations($string = ''){
    $this->set('aResult', array(0=>'Florida', 1=>'London'));
    $this->set('_serialize', 'aResult');
}
```

Finally, you can see the results in your browser **mysite/app/pages/getlocations.json**

Doing this way CakePHP will add the application/json headers automatically.

More info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html